# Magento 2: Undefined class constant 'PUB' in index.php

Tags: magento2, php

```
$params[\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = [
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList::PUB => [\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA => [\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
];
```

Comment: Please add more description, question's intend is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

can you please try 
Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

instead of 
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList

Hope it will work !!

Comment: please accept as answer if it is useful.